# How can I make this code cleaner and easier to maintain and read? Refactoring

Tags: refactoring

How can I refactor this?
How can I make this code cleaner and easier to maintain and read?
Thanks in advance

I'm a newbie. I'm trying to do a cleaner style of coding. I'm currently working on making this simple game to practice. I'm not sure if this looks clean enough or it can be better. I will really appreciate your help.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

public class Honey {
   private int w;
   private int h;
   private int x;
   private int y;
   private int sx;
   private int endHoneyImage;
   private int timer;
   private static Image img;
   private static Toolkit tk;
   private boolean isEmpty;
   private boolean sxChecker;

   static {
      Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
      img = tk.getImage("res/honeyIndex(15X15).png");
   }

   public Honey() {
      this(45, 45);
   }
   public Honey(int x, int y) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      w = 15;
      h = 15;
      isEmpty = false;
      timer = 0;
      sx = 4 * w;
      sxChecker = true;
      endHoneyImage=60;
   }

   public void update() { 
      if (isEmpty) { 
         timer++; 
         if (timer >= 60 ) {
            sx += w; 
            if (sxChecker) {
               sx = 0;
               sxChecker= false;
            }
            timer = 0; // 
            if (sx == endHoneyImage) { 
               isEmpty = false; 
               sxChecker = true;
            }
         }
      }

   }


   public void draw(Graphics g, HoneyBeeCanvas honeyBeeCanvas) {

      g.drawImage(img, x, y, x + w, y + h, sx, 0, sx + w, h, honeyBeeCanvas);
   }

   public int getX() {
      return x;
   }

   public void setX(int x) {
      this.x = x;
   }

   public int getY() {
      return y;
   }

   public void setY(int y) {
      this.y = y;
   }



   public void onHoney(Point[] point) {
      for (int z = 0; z < point.length; z++) {
         if ((point[z].x > (x - 8)) && (point[z].x < (x + 8)) && (point[z].y > (y - 8)) && (point[z].y < (y + 8))) {
            point[z].honey = true;
            isEmpty = true;
         }
      }
   }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start by refactoring the method `draw`

1. Add a parameter `Honey`
2. Use only the properties of the new parameter
3. Extract the `draw` method to a new class `HoneyDrawer`

This will remove some bad 'static' initialisations and will simplify the `Honey` class